# Build and Release Ember App to Azure Service Fabric

Tags: ember.js, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

currently our process works, but it takes too much time due that the fronend Ember app needs to be build into every single environment we have ( 5 environments ). because we never know which environment will be available when we release it.
we intend to add even more environments because every developer should have his own working development environment. (because of the backend)

how we do it, is that we create a frontend build and a backend build which creates artifacts. 
now the frontent build takes around 2 minutes for every environment. 
ember build --env=test and ember build --env=acceptance and ember build --env=development ... and more

when the artifacts are created we then create the release picking the correct ones depending on which environment we release (this done via release pipeline).

my question is can we make a frontend ember build somehow not depending on the environment?
i would like to note that we are using azure service fabric.

Comment: if you can configure it at startup - i dont see a problem

Comment: If it is the configuration that changes we use https://github.com/blimmer/ember-cli-server-variables to allow our server generated index.html file to inject configuration into the ember app it loads. This let's us build just one app but use it in several places.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anyway around multiple Ember builds because each one will be different (i.e. production vs. development). 
You can batch together each build inside one CI build/build task and produce artifact(s) to be used in your release pipeline.

Run the following command once for each environment you have (assuming you are using Ember-CLI) sequentially in one build task.

`ember build --environment={{YOUR-ENV-HERE}} --output-path="dist/{{YOUR-ENV-HERE}}/"`

You can then either upload the entire `dist/` folder as an artifact and scope each environment in your release pipeline to the corresponding artifact subdirectory, or you can upload each folder inside `/dist` as an individual artifact and scope each environment in your release pipeline to its corresponding artifact.

Comment: Yeah, this is basically what we are doing, but for a build (which can be used for any release) we need to build for all existing environments. which takes too much time, and we probably end up using only for one environment anyway.

Comment: Is it only configuration that changes based off of your environment? Or does the ember code change too?

Answer (score 0):

only the configuration it changes. basically the api endpoints